# Convert a letter string to a pure letter for use in .match regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I have an array of alphabets in the form of letter strings

```
alpha = ['a','b', etc..];
```

I'm counting up numbers of each letter in a word like so

```
for (j=0;j<alpha.length;j++){
    num = word.match(/alpha[j]/g).length;}
```

Problem is that, for example, `alpha[0]` is `'a'`, not `a` and match regex only recognizes `a` .
How can I convert from `'a'` to `a` so that match recognizes it?

To clarify

`"ara".match(/a/g)` returns `["a","a"]` while `"ara".match(/'a'/g)` returns `null`.

Comment: If there is no matching letter, *match* will return `null` and attempting `null.length` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a RegExp from a string with the RegExp constructor as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
for (j=0;j<alpha.length;j++){
    var matches = word.match(new RegExp(alpha[j], "g"));
    if (matches) {
       num = matches.length;
       // other code here to process the match
    }
}
```

This assumes that none of the characters in the alpha array will be special characters in a regular expression because if they are, you will have to escape them so they are treated as normal characters.

Answer (score 0):

As jfriend00 suggests, you can use the RegExp constructor like:

```
var re, num, matches;

for (j=0; j<alpha.length; j++){
    re = new RegExp(alpha[j],'g');
    matches = word.match(re);
    num = matches? matches.length : 0;
}
```

Note that another way (shorter, faster, simpler) is:

```
var num = word.split('a').length - 1; // 'ara' -> 2
```